# Unknown provider: ServiceProvider <- Service <- Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

Been banging my head on this issue for hours now and can't seem to find the solution on SO.

I have the following:

```
//controller.js
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('seed-module')
    .controller('SeedPageController', SeedPageController);

SeedPageController.$inject = ['companyListPrepService', 'logger'];

function SeedPageController(companyListPrepService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.companies = companyListPrepService;
    console.log(vm.companies.data);

}

angular
    .module('seed-module')
    .factory('companyListService', companyListService);

companyListService.$inject = ['$http', 'logger'];

function companyListService($http, logger) {
    return {
        getCompanies: getCompanies
    };


    function getCompanies() {
        return $http.get('/companies.json')
            .success(function (data) {
                return data;
        })
            .error(function (error) {
                logger.error('XHR Failed for .' + error);
        });


    }
}
```

And for my routes:

```
//seed.config.js
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('seed-module')
    .config(moduleConfig);

/* @ngInject */
function moduleConfig($translatePartialLoaderProvider, $stateProvider, triMenuProvider) {
    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/seed-module');

    $stateProvider
    .state('triangular.admin-default.seed-page', {
        resolve: {
        companyListPrepService : companyListPrepService
        },
        url: '/seed-module/seed-page',
        templateUrl: 'app/seed-module/seed-page.tmpl.html',
        // set the controller to load for this page
        controller: 'SeedPageController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
}

function companyListPrepService(companyListService) {
    return companyListService.getCompanies();
}
})();
```

My console.log(vm.companies.data); gives me the object at the end of my REST endpoint, however, i get an

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: companyListPrepServiceProvider <- companyListPrepService <- SeedPageController.

I'm relatively new to AngularJS and have no clue where the companyListPrepServiceProvider is coming from. I don't even know where to debug this...any thoughts?

Comment: Could it be you're missing the `$inject` array for your `companyListPrepService` function?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `$http` `success` and `error` methods any more, they have been deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working as is. There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yHnyIBqPT737Q4mw8wXL?p=preview), with its part AS IS. *(it is true, that mixture of strict notation is not good, we should use explicit `$inject = [...]` everywhere - but it is not a problem here)*

So, what could be the issue? I would say, that the controller `SeedPageController` is used elswhere, in some other state, which does **NOT** contain the resolve statement:

```
resolve: {
  //companyListPrepService : companyListPrepService
},
```

There is such [broken example](http://plnkr.co/edit/m6toTA74NITXEgp5uSo0?p=preview) with the error message experienced above

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: companyListPrepServiceProvider <- companyListPrepService <- SeedPageController

Comment: Looked through the code and didn't find any other cases where `SeedPageController` is used elsewhere, unfortunately.

Comment: The good is, that you have my plunker. Check there, that your code is working there. Play with ... and it should show you where is the issue at the end. As just proven, your code is working ;) Hope it'll help a bit...

Comment: What about `ng-controller`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're minifying your code and as such, you're missing the DI annotation for your `companyListPrepService` function. Try adding

```
companyListPrepService.$inject = ['companyListService'];
```

to `seed.config.js`.

---

Alternatively, try just using an array annotated function

```
resolve: {
    companyListPrepService: ['companyListService', function(companyListService) {
        return companyListService.getCompanies().then(function(response) {
            // as mentioned in comments, stop using "success"
            return response.data;
        });
    }]
}
```

Comment: where in seed.config.js? I've tried putting it inside `moduleConfig()`, `companyListPrepService()` and outside   `moduleConfig()`. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @Dominooch in the same scope as the `companyListPrepService` function

Comment: still get the same error. `companyListPrepService.$inject = ['companyListService'];

    function companyListPrepService(companyListService) {...}`

Comment: @Dominooch I'm not sure then but I've added some more to my answer